# VHDL type conversion - found 4 possible definitions

Tags: vhdl

I am trying convert two std_logic bits to an integer as follows

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.numeric_std.ALL;

ENTITY TEST IS
    PORT (sw1, sw0  :   IN      std_logic;
          x         :   OUT     integer RANGE 3 DOWNTO 0);
END ENTITY TEST;

ARCHITECTURE dflow OF TEST IS
    SIGNAL mes_sel : integer RANGE 3 DOWNTO 0;
BEGIN
    mes_sel <= to_integer(unsigned(std_logic_vector(SW1 & SW0)));
    x <= mes_sel;
END ARCHITECTURE dflow;
```

but the compiler does not like the mes_sel assignment. I get the following compiler error message:

> Error (10327): VHDL error at Q4.vhd(92): can't determine definition of operator ""&"" -- found 4 possible definitions

Can I not concatenate 2 bit of std_logic to a vector and then convert? Or is it something else?
regards
D

Comment: What does it not like? Did it, like, give an error message or something? (Incidentally you can form an `unsigned` directly from two std_logics, there should be no need to go via std_logic_vector)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message tells you roughly what's wrong, and it's not a problem with the assignment.

GHDL gives a better diagnosis:

> ghdl -a test.vhd
>   test.vhd:13:57: can't resolve overload for operator "&"
>   test.vhd:13:57: possible interpretations are:
>   ../../src/ieee/numeric_std.v93:66:18: array type "signed"
>   ../../src/ieee/numeric_std.v93:65:20: array type "unsigned"
>   ../../src/ieee/std_logic_1164.v93:69:30: array type "std_logic_vector"
>   ../../src/ieee/std_logic_1164.v93:54:31: array type "std_ulogic_vector"
>   ghdl: compilation error

VHDL allows overloaded operators, distinguishable by the types of their arguments (in this case, std_logic) and their return types, (in this case ... well... what?)

There are apparently 4 types which have a `std_logic_vector()` type conversion function declared on them, as well as a `&` operator taking two std_logic arguments; and ghdl (unlike whatever tool you're using) helpfully lists them.

In such cases, VHDL (unlike some other languages) insists that you pick one, rather than arbitrarily making a hidden (and possibly wrong) choice for you.

You can do this with a type mark. As you actually want an `unsigned`, the obvious choice is `unsigned'()` (note the "'" symbol, also used for attributes).

```
mes_sel <= to_integer(unsigned'(SW1 & SW0));
```

Note that if VHDL allowed anything simpler, like `to_integer(SW1 & SW0)` it would be positively dangerous as there is nothing to distinguish between signed and unsigned conversions, making the conversion at least non-obvious, and quite possibly wrong.

Comment: If i'm following correctly, then, the synthesis tool needs a hint at what the concatenation of the 2 std_logic bits will result too, before, making the conversion, because in the functions for overloading contained in the std lib's there are 4 definitions? Does this sound like I am thinking about this in the right way? As always Thanks for the great reply.

Comment: You right. Actually there are 3 packages loaded: the default types and functions from VHDL (library std), and `std_logic_1164` and `numeric_std` from library IEEE. P.S. if your entity is just doing a conversion, maybe it's better to move that code into a function.

Comment: @DannyJ yes that's it - the concatenation is what the `&` function returns - and there are 4 such functions returning 4 different types. What I'm doing is not a *conversion* to `unsigned` but a *specification* if you like, that the result should be unsigned to remove the ambiguity. (Then `to_integer` is a conversion). Now if I had assigned `SW1 & SW0` to an intermediate variable or signal, its declaration would have specified the type - so no problem. (And it doesn't cost any more hardware, by the way. So that's an acceptable alternative solution)

Comment: And if you had a -2008 compliant VHDL tool and specified package `numeric_std_unsigned` instead of `numeric_std` you could express the assignment as `mes_sel <= to_integer(SW1 & SW0);`. This removes any ambiguity between types, supplying a `to_integer` conversion function for std_logic_vector which is a resolved std_ulogic_vector in -2008 and not providing signed/unsigned ambiguity.