# why do i get this "4 possible definitions" VHDL concatenation error

Tags: vhdl

I get an error message for this line:

```
DATA (15 DOWNTO 0)  <=  regs(to_integer(unsigned(REG_ADR_HI & REG_ADR_LO)) - 40000);
```

*Error (10327): VHDL error at main.vhd(216): can't determine definition of operator ""&"" -- found 4 possible definitions*

`REG_ADR_HI`, `REG_ADR_LO` and `DATA` are all `STD_LOGIC_VECTOR`s - `(7 DOWNTO 0)`, `(7 DOWNTO 0)` and `(15 DOWNTO 0)`

may be I use to many libs at once. but not sure what is exactly wrong.

when I try [to go this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35102097/vhdl-type-conversion-found-4-possible-definitions) I get the other one:

*Error (10327): VHDL error at main.vhd(216): can't determine definition of operator ""&"" -- found 0 possible definitions*

So how can I fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VHDL type conversion - found 4 possible definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35102097/vhdl-type-conversion-found-4-possible-definitions)

Comment: please notice the " when I try to go this way I get the other one: ... " part

Comment: Yes but notice you didn't demonstrate that in your question and you don't provide a [mcve]. Show the declaration for regs. Also note the offset arithmetic for the regs index appears to be able to go out of bounds.

Comment: Constructing a [mcve] shows this would work -  `DATA (15 DOWNTO 0) <=  regs(to_integer (unsigned(REG_ADR_HI) & unsigned(REG_ADR_LO)) - 40000);` with the exception that when the concatenated binary unsigned value is less that 4000 the index will go negative. Without seeing the declaration that would pretty much be guaranteed to go out of bounds of the array type for used for `regs`.

Comment: And this one would work for the linked question - `DATA (15 DOWNTO 0)  <=  regs(to_integer(unsigned(std_logic_vector'(REG_ADR_HI & REG_ADR_LO))) - 40000);` (With the same bounds index bounds issue.)